# Does anybody have a script that counts the number of consecutive files which contain a specific word?

Tags: bash, scripting

Any resources or advice would help, since I am pretty rubbish at scripting

So, I need to go to this path:  /home/client/data/storage/customer/data/2020/09/15

And check to see if there are 5 or more consecutive files that contain the word "REJECTED":

```
ls -ltr

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  5059 Sep 15 00:05 customer_rlt_20200915000514737_20200915000547948_8206b49d-b585-4360-8da0-e90b8081a399.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  5023 Sep 15 00:06 customer_rlt_20200915000547619_20200915000635576_900b44dc-1cf4-4b1b-a04f-0fd963591e5f.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 39856 Sep 15 00:09 customer_rlt_20200915000824108_20200915000908982_b87b01b3-a5dc-4a80-b19d-14f31ff667bc.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 39719 Sep 15 00:09 customer_rlt_20200915000901688_20200915000938206_38261b59-8ebc-4f9f-9e2d-3e32eca3fd4d.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 12829 Sep 15 00:13 customer_rlt_20200915001229811_20200915001334327_1667be2f-f1a7-41ae-b9ca-e7103d9abbf8.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 12706 Sep 15 00:13 customer_rlt_20200915001333922_20200915001357405_609195c9-f23a-4984-936f-1a0903a35c07.zip
```

Example of rejected file:

```
customer_rlt_20200513202515792_20200513202705506_5b8deae0-0405-413c-9a81-d1cc2171fa51REJECTED.zip
```

What I have so far:

```
!/bin/bash

YYYY=$(date +%Y);
MM=$(date +%m)
DD=$(date +%d)

#Set constants
CODE_OK=0
CODE_WARN=1
CODE_CRITICAL=2
CODE_UNKNOWN=3

#Set Default Values
FILE="/home/client/data/storage/customer/data/${YYYY}/${MM}/{DD}"

if [ ! -f $FILE ]
then
  echo "NO TRANSACTIONS FOUND"
  exit $CODE_CRITICAL
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive files? Filename, last modification date, ...? What did you try to find out five consecutive files?

Comment: `consecutive files` What are "consecutive" files? Files are not ordered, they all belong to the same directory without any particular ordering. As there is no ordering, there are no "consecutive files".

Comment: so, on this path : /home/client/data/storage/customer/data/${YYYY}/${MM}/{DD}, each day a new dir is created, and the files above are like transactions, and if there are 5 consecutive REJECTED transactions to receive a critical status . I was thinking about using find: $find . -type f -name "*.zip" | awk -v key='REJECTED.zip' '{if($1==key) c++; else {print c; c=0}} END {print c}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something quick in AWK:

```
$ cat consec.awk
/REJECTED/ {
    if (match_line == NR - 1) {
        consecutives++
    } else {
        consecutives = 1
    }
    if (consecutives == 5) {
        print "5 REJECTED"
        exit
    }
    match_line = NR
}
$ touch 1 2REJECTED 3REJECTED 5REJECTED 6REJECTED 7REJECTED 8
$ ls -1 | awk -f consec.awk
5 REJECTED
$ rm 3REJECTED; touch 3
$ ls -1 | awk -f consec.awk
$
```

This works by matching line containing `REJECTED`, counting consecutive lines (checked with `match_line == NR - 1`, which means "the last matching line was the previous line") and printing "5 REJECTED" if the number of consecutive lines is 5.

I've used `ls -1` (note digit `1`, not letter `l`) to sort by filename in this example. You could use `ls -1rt` (digit `1` again) to sort by file modification time, as in your original post.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much @Jon